# Insert Image PhpWord

Tags: php, image, symfony, phpword, phpoffice

I can add images using URL but not trying to get a local image file.

```
$portada->addImage('earth.jpg');
```

Getting this error:

> Uncaught PHP Exception PhpOffice\PhpWord\Exception\InvalidImageException: "" at C:\Users\kaskull\Desktop\symfony\examsgenerator\vendor\phpoffice\phpword\src\PhpWord\Element\Image.php line 386

I'm createing my Word on a controller so my first idea is that should be something like this:

```
$portada->addImage('../Resources/Asset/images/logo.png');
```

Getting the same error.

**EDIT:**

If i do:

```
$path = realpath('../Resources/Asset/images/logo.png');var_dump(is_readable($path));
```

It returns FALSE

But if i use this, it runs.

```
$path=realpath('C:\Users\CARLES\Desktop\symfony\examsfinal\src\AppBundle\Resources\Asset\images\logo.png');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say you have the following folder structure:

```
C:\Users\kaskull\Desktop\symfony\examsgenerator\src\AppBundle\Controllers\MyController.php

C:\Users\kaskull\Desktop\symfony\examsgenerator\src\AppBundle\Resources\Asset\images\logo.png
```

**UPDATE:**

Try this in your controller:

```
$path = realpath(__DIR__ . '/../Resources/Asset/images/logo.png');
$portada->addImage($path);
```

`__DIR__` in PHP is the directory of the file ([documentation link](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php)). You need that because your controller class is executed from the other file context. That is why your relative path doesn't work.

Comment: This is what exactly i'm doing and how my folders are structured, and i'm getting that error.